# Mongoose .select is not a function when using with Azure Function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, mongoose, azure-functions

I'm trying to use mongoose .select operator with my azure function but it keeps saying `TypeError: db.collection(...).findOne(...).select is not a function     at db.collection.find.toArray`
It returns the user's data in the console, but doesn't filter it down with `.select`
Why is that?

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Post = require('./model/post');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = async function (context, req) {

  let currentPage = 1;


  MongoClient.connect(process.env.CosmosDBConnectionString, async (err, client) => {




    let send = response(client, context);

    if (err) send(500, err.message);

    let db = client.db(process.env.dbName);


    await db.collection('listings').find(
      {
        $and: [
          { winnerHasBeenNotified: false },
          { auctionEndDateTime: { $lte: Date.now().toString() } }
        ]
      }
    )

      .toArray((err, result) => {
        console.log("result");
        console.log(result);


        if (result) {

          for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

            db.collection('users').findOne(
              {

                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result[i].bidderId)

              }
            ).select("notificationBy").toArray((err, result) => {
              console.log("USER RESULT!");
              console.log(result);
            });


          }


        }




        if (err) send(500, err.message);
        send(200, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));



      });
  });




};

function response(client, context) {
  return function (status, body) {
    context.res = {
      status: status,
      body: body
    };

    client.close();
    context.done();
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`find()` returns a cursor, which has a `select` method.  [findOne()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Collection.html#findOne) retrieves a single document and returns a promise if no callback is provided.

If you are trying to get just the "notificationBy" field, try passing the `fields` option to findOne.

Comment: There could be more than 1 winner returned at a time. The idea is to do a timer azure function GET every 10mins all the winners that have ```winnerHasBeenNotified = false``` returned. Then I'm gonna send an email to those users and update the value in DB to true. I'm a little confused by what you mean when you say fields option. Can you provide an example?